# Jsoup set proxy

Tags: proxy, jsoup

I'm trying to use JSoup through a proxy. It's working great, when I just use a new proxy (http://incloak.com/proxy-list/), But when I change a good IP i.e.  107.165.33.12:3128 -> 10**6**.165.33.12:3128 it shouldn't work cause the IP is not an existing proxy. but it still gets the page only with my own IP-address.

What can I do against this problem, I want to get some sort of error when the proxy isn't working.

useProxy.java

```
public class useProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "107.165.33.12");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.toolsvoid.com/what-is-my-ip-address") //http://goldenpirates.org/proxy/azenv.php
                            .ignoreContentType(true)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                            .referrer("http://www.google.nl/")  
                            .timeout(12000) 
                            .followRedirects(true)
                            .header("Accept-Language", "en")
                            .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch")
                            .get();

        String iP = doc.select("table.list").select("strong").first().text(); //get used IP.
        String info = doc.select("textarea").text(); //get used IP.


        System.out.println("IP-Adres: " + iP);
        System.out.println("Info: \n" + info);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna like doing it this way....

```
    final String authUser = "USERNAME";
    final String authPassword = "PASSWORD";



    Authenticator.setDefault(
                   new Authenticator() {
                      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                         return new PasswordAuthentication(
                               authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
                      }
                   }
                );

    ..

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
    ..
```